# multicolumn csv text into presence absence matri

Tags: r, csv, text, binary

I have a csv file like this:

```
    col1    col2    col3
r1  a,b,c   e,f      g
r2  h,i             j,k
r3  l      m,n,o
```

some cells have multiple text comma separated, some have single and some have none.I want to convert this like:

```
   col1  col2  col3
a   1     0     0
b   1     0     0
c   1     0     0
e   0     1     0
f   0     1     0
g   0     0     1
h   1     0     0
i   1     0     0
j   0     0     1
k   0     0     1
l   1     0     0
m   0     1     0
n   0     1     0
o   0     1     0
```

Any suggestion? I tried pivot table in excel but not getting the desired output.
Thanks in advance.

Best Regards
Zillur

Comment: In Excel use `countif()`

Answer (score 0):

not sure whether this is the shortest solution (probably not) but it produces the desired output. Basically, we go through all three columns and count the occurrences of the strings and get a long format data frame that we then flip to the wide format you want.

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data_frame(col1 = c("a,b,c", "h,i", "l"),
             col2 = c("e,f", "", "m,n,o"),
             col3 = c("g", "j,k", ""))

let_df <- map_df(df, function(col){
  # map_df applies the function to each column of df

  # split strings at "," and unlist to get vector of letters 
  letters <- unlist(str_split(col, ","))
  # delete "" 
  letters <- letters[nchar(letters) > 0]

  # count occurrences for each letter
  tab <- table(letters)

  # replace with 1 if occurs more often
  tab[tab > 1] <- 1 

  # create data frame from table
  df <- data_frame(letter = names(tab), count = tab) 
  return(df)
}, .id = "col") # id adds a column col that contains col1 - col3

# bring data frame into wide format 
let_df %>% 
  spread(col, count, fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a great problem to solve. Here is my take on it in base R:

```
col1 <- c("a,b,c","h,i","l")
col2 <- c("e,f","","m,n,o")
col3 <- c("g","j,k","")
data <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, stringsAsFactors = F)

restructure <- function(df){
df[df==""] <- "missing"
result_rows <- as.character()
l <- list()
for (i in seq_along(colnames(df)) ){
  df_col <- sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(gsub(" ", "",toString(df[[i]])), ","))))
  df_col <- df_col[!df_col %in% "missing"]
  result_rows <- sort(unique(c(result_rows, df_col)))
  l[i] <- list(df_col)
}
result <- data.frame(result_rows)
for (j in seq_along(l)){
  result$temp <- NA
  result$temp[match(l[[j]], result_rows)] <- 1
  colnames(result)[colnames(result)=="temp"] <- colnames(df)[j]
}
result[is.na(result)] <- 0
return(result)
}

> restructure(data)
#  result_rows col1 col2 col3
#1            a    1    0    0
#2            b    1    0    0
#3            c    1    0    0
#4            e    0    1    0
#5            f    0    1    0
#6            g    0    0    1
#7            h    1    0    0
#8            i    1    0    0
#9            j    0    0    1
#10           k    0    0    1
#11           l    1    0    0
#12           m    0    1    0
#13           n    0    1    0
#14           o    0    1    0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly. I think this will lead to a publication and if it happens, I will acknowledge there also. Best Regards Zillur